# Entering a floating point number, not reaching the error message

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program for this assignment:

> Write a program to prompt for a score between 0.0 and 1.0. If the score is out of range, print an error. If the score is between 0.0 and 1.0, print a grade using the following table:
>
> ```
> Score Grade  
> >= 0.9 A
> >= 0.8 B
> >= 0.7 C
> >= 0.6 D
> < 0.6 F
> ```
>
> If the user enters a value out of range, print a suitable error message and exit.

But it doesn't print the sentence.

```
try:
    inp = raw_input("Enter Score: ")    

    score = float(inp)

except:
    print "Please enter a score number between 0.0 and 1.0"  
    quit()
if score >= 0.9 :
    print "A" 
elif score >= 0.8 :
    print "B"    
elif score >= 0.7 :
    print "C"    
elif score >= 0.6 :
    print "D" 
elif score < 0.6 :
    print "F"
else:
    print "Your score number is not in the 0 - 1 range."
```

Comment: Can you show the traceback and the error that you do get?

Comment: Actually numbers that are already greater than `0.9` the first `if` statement gets evaluated.

Comment: the error that i got is " Please correct your code and re-run. "

Comment: @pavan: what happens when you run your code **locally**, not in your assignment test environment?

Comment: Martijn Pieters--my assignment in test environment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should raise the exception to get it printed. Here is the code changes that you are looking for.

```
try:
    inp = raw_input("Enter Score: ")    

    score = float(inp)

    if score > 1.0 or score < 0
        raise
except:
    print "Please enter a score number between 0.0 and 1.0"  
    quit()
if score >= 0.9 :
    print "A" 
elif score >= 0.8 :
    print "B"    
elif score >= 0.7 :
    print "C"    
elif score >= 0.6 :
    print "D" 
elif score < 0.6 :
    print "F"
else:
    #your logic
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: please explain that if statement

Answer (score 1):

```
score = input("Enter Score: ")
scor = float(score)

if 0.0 < scor > 1.0:
    print("error")
elif scor >= 0.9:
    print("A")
elif scor >= 0.8:
    print("B")
elif scor >= 0.7:
    print("C")
elif scor >= 0.6:
    print("D")
elif scor < 0.6:
    print("F")
```

Answer (score 0):

So like I highlighted in the comment section please make the modifications to your `if` statement like below:

```
try:
  inp = raw_input("Enter Score: ")    

  score = float(inp)

except:
   print "Please enter a score number between 0.0 and 1.0"  
   quit()

# change your if statement here:
if score > 1.0 or score < 0.0:
   print "Your score number is not in the 0 - 1 range." 
elif score >= 0.9 :
  print "A" 
elif score >= 0.8 :
   print "B"    
elif score >= 0.7 :
   print "C"    
elif score >= 0.6 :
   print "D" 
elif score < 0.6 :
   print "F"
```

EDIT: First of all the `if` branch checks for an out of bound `score` which is a value above 1.0 and below 0.0, then prints an error message.
If the `score` is within limits than the other `elif` blocks check to value of the `score` as in the original post.

Comment: please explain that "if"statement

Answer (score 0):

Pavan, your code doesn't pass the exam, because you accept values which are higher than 1.0 or smaller than 0.0 which is incorrect.

Add a check somewhere which validates that the score is between 0.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = input("Enter score between 0.0 and 1.0:")
score = float(inp)

if score >= 0.9 and score <= 1.0:
    print("A")
if score >= 0.8 and score < 0.9:
    print("B")
if score >= 0.7 and score < 0.8:
    print("C")
if score >= 0.6 and score < 0.7:
    print("D")
if score >= 0.0 and score <0.6:
    print("F")
elif score > 1.0:
    print("Error, please enter score between 0.0 and 1.0")
    quit()
```

Comment: Well, actually im learning an online course on python for everybody by Michigan university from coursera and i came across this assignment, and likewise i was having trouble solving this, well i took some help from the post below and modified the elif score > 1.0 line and viola it executed as it was supposed to. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
scr=(input("Enter the Score: "))
try:
    scr=float(scr)
    if scr>=0.0 and scr<=1.0:
        if scr >= 0.9:
            print("A")
        elif scr >= 0.8:
            print("B")
        elif scr >= 0.7:
            print("C")
        elif scr >= 0.6:
            print("D")
        elif scr<0.6:
            print("F")
    else:
        print("Out Of range")
except:
    print("Try a number")
```

**Explanation:**
scr is the score which will take float as input ranging from 0.0 to 1.0. If the score is less than 0.0 or greater than 1.0 then it prints "Out of Range". If entered input is not float/ int then it will print "Try a Number".

Answer (score -1):

```
inp = input("Enter a Score between 0.0 and 1.0")
score = float(inp)

if score >= 0.9 and score <=1.0: 
    print ('A')
elif score >= 0.8 and score <0.9:
    print ('B')
elif score >= 0.7 and score <0.8:
    print ('C')
elif score >= 0.6 and score <0.7:
    print ('D')
elif score >= 0.0 and score <0.6:
    print ('F')
elif score > 1.0 or score < 0.0:
    print ("Error, the score should be in the range between 0.0 and 1.0")
quit()
```